# Downloading an image from Drive API v3 continuously gives corrupt images. How should I decode the response from the promise?

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I'm trying to download images from a Google share Drive using the API v3. The download itself will succeed but the image can't be seen. Opening the image from the MacOS finder just results in a spinner.
I started using the example from the documentation (here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads):

```
const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});

// ....

var fileId = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M';
var dest = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/photo.jpg');
drive.files.get({
  fileId: fileId,
  alt: 'media'
})
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log('Done');
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('Error during download', err);
    })
    .pipe(dest);
```

however that fails because the .on() method doesn't exist. The exact error is **"TypeError: drive.files.get(...).on is not a function"**

The .get() method returns a promise. The response of the promise contains data that, depending on the config is either a stream, a blob or arraybuffer. For all options, when I write the response data to a file, the file itself becomes unviewable and has the wrong size. The actual code (typescript, node.js) for the arraybuffer example is below. Similar code for blob (with added name and modifiedDate) and for stream give the same result.

```
        const downloader = googleDrive.files.get({
            fileId: file.id,
            alt: 'media',
        }, {
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        });

        return downloader
            .then((response) => {

                const targetFile = file.id + '.' + file.extension;

                fs.writeFileSync(targetFile, response.data);

                return response.status;
            })
            .catch((response) => {
                    logger.error('Error in Google Drive service download: ' + response.message);
                    return response.message;
                }
            );
    }
```

So the questions are:

- what is the correct way to handle a download through Google Drive API v3 ?
- do I need to handle any formatting of the response data ?

All help greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You want to download a file from Google Drive using googleapis with Node.js.
- You have already been able to use Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `arraybuffer` is used for `responseType`.

#### Sample script:

```
const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
var fileId = '###';  // Please set the file ID.
drive.files.get(
  {
    fileId: fileId,
    alt: "media"
  },
  { responseType: "arraybuffer" },
  function(err, { data }) {
    fs.writeFile("sample.jpg", Buffer.from(data), err => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    });
  }
);
```

- In this case, `Buffer.from()` is used.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `stream` is used for `responseType`.

#### Sample script:

```
const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
var fileId = '###';  // Please set the file ID.
var dest = fs.createWriteStream("sample.jpg");
drive.files.get(
  {
    fileId: fileId,
    alt: "media"
  },
  { responseType: "stream" },
  function(err, { data }) {
    data
      .on("end", () => {
        console.log("Done");
      })
      .on("error", err => {
        console.log("Error during download", err);
      })
      .pipe(dest);
  }
);
```

### Note:

- If an error occurs, please use the latest version of googleapis.
- From your question, it seems that you have already been able to retrieve the file you want to download using your request, while the file content cannot be opened. But if an error occurs, please try to add `supportsAllDrives: true` and/or `supportsTeamDrives: true` in the request.

### References:

- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)
- [google-api-nodejs-client/samples/drive/download.js](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/drive/download.js)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Pattern 1 was effective without further changes. Thanks

Comment: @Yom Mark Filius Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Posting a third pattern for completeness using async/await and including teamdrive files.

```
async function downloadFile(drive: Drive, file: Schema$File, localDir: string = "/tmp/downloads") {
  if (!fs.existsSync(localDir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(localDir)
  }

  const outputStream = fs.createWriteStream(`${localDir}/${file.name}`);

  const { data } = await drive.files.get({
    corpora: 'drive',
    includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
    supportsAllDrives: true,
    fileId: file.id,
    alt: "media",
  }, {
    responseType: 'stream',
  })

  await pipeline(data, outputStream)

  console.log(`Downloaded file: ${localDir}/${file.name}`)
}
```